# Find smaller strings inside of a larger one

Tags: python, string, file, find

Im trying to write some logic that loops through a file of strings (County names) and checks to see if they are in a larger string from another file (Severe Weather Warnings). Everything i've read tells me im doing this correctly however the code is not matching up. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my skeleton code.

## program to test county warning filtering

```
file1 = 'path/to/file1'
file2 = 'path/to/file2'

fp = open(file1,'rb')
string = fp.read()
fp.close()


file = open(file2,'rb')

for line in file:
    if line in string:
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")
```

example of file 1:

```
BULLETIN - IMMEDIATE BROADCAST REQUESTED  
SEVERE THUNDERSTORM WARNING  
NATIONAL WEATHER SERVICE JACKSON MS  
457 PM CDT MON AUG 4 2014  

THE NATIONAL WEATHER SERVICE IN JACKSON HAS ISSUED A  

* SEVERE THUNDERSTORM WARNING FOR...  
  EASTERN FRANKLIN COUNTY IN SOUTHWEST MISSISSIPPI...  
  CENTRAL LINCOLN COUNTY IN SOUTH CENTRAL MISSISSIPPI...  

* UNTIL 545 PM CDT
```

Example of file2:

```
FRANKLIN COUNTY

LINCOLN COUNTY

Ect...
```

Comment: use `with` to open your file, it will close them for you automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line` contains linebreaks (`'\n'`).

Try changing

```
if line in string:
```

to

```
if line.strip() in string:
```

Comment: Thank you! I had suspected that invisible chars were causing the issue! Also thank you for the edit on the post.

Comment: @Twisterkid34 please consider accepting this

Comment: I did Elisha thank you.